# difficulties in drupal with encoding

Tags: php, drupal, utf-8, warnings, encode

i would like to work on a website in order to develop other fonctionalities. It works on the server but not in localhost. I use MAMP on my MAC
I use the server project.

The errors are :

- Notice : Trying to get property of non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/var/www/includes/path.inc on line 51

  Sélectionner tout - Visualiser dans une fenêtre à part
  $path_language = $path_language ? $path_language : $language->language ;
- warning : Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/var/www/includes/path.inc:51) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/var/www/includes/common.inc on line 148.

  if (strlen($header)) {
  header($header) ;
  $stored_headers[] = $header ;
  }
- warning : array_merge() [function.array-merge] : Argument #2 is not an array in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/var/www/includes/theme.inc on line 976.

  $settings = array_merge($settings, variable_get(str_replace(‘/’, ‘’, ‘theme’. $key .’_settings’), array())) ;

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting a fresh copy from the server to your machine following theses steps:

- Get a database backup of the server
- Create a database locally with the same collation as the server
- Copy the files from the server to your machine while reserving their permissions, rsync would be a great tool to do that
- alter drupal's settings file "sites/default/settings.php" to match your local database, it now should work fine